# how to call css class as function in html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

how can I achieve calling css class as function? I don't want to generate classes for each width value? is there any solution like the following ?

> I am trying to update style's width value according to back-end code
>   (width represents product's amount).

```
<style>
    .dynamicWidth(@param){
    width:@param px;
    }
</style>

    <div class='dynamicWidth(40)'></div>
```

I can solve it by using inline style code, but I don't want to use inline style code, because of content security policy.

```
//I don't want to use it like this.

<style>
  .dynamicWidth{
        dynamicWidth:var (--param);
  }
</style>
<div class="dynamicWidth" style="--param : 40;"></div>
```

Comment: style="width: XXpx;" but thats not a good idea (you should know what widths on which elements are you using)

Comment: You can not use css class as function in html. you can use JQuery function toachieve your task

Comment: @PavelTřupek I don't wanna use inline style

Comment: @HardikLeuwa can I achieve it using LESS or SCSS ?

Comment: @more2know so you don't want `style=""`, but would it be ok if the `style` attribute is added via JS? Or would that also fall into your content security policy, since it basically does that same? I don't think it's possible without `style` attribute (added either manually or with JS). Except if you're allowed to use `data-attributes` (e.g. data-width="50px")?

Comment: @elveti no problem for using style in js, it could be handled by adding some CSP hashing attributes to it.

Comment: Can you use a data attribute (`data-width`) rather than the class attribute? Would be much safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with javascript:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamicWidth");

Array.from(elements).forEach((element) => {
  element.style.width = element.getAttribute("data-width") + "px";
});
```

```css
.dynamicWidth {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='dynamicWidth' data-width='40'></div>
<div class='dynamicWidth' data-width='60'></div>
<div class='dynamicWidth' data-width='90'></div>
```

Comment: Impressive, but very fragile in practice. If there's anything else (deliberately or via a backend or JS library) added to the class value, kablooey.